# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm pretty new to React and I am trying to follow along with a tutorial however I get the following error message when the script attempts to compile:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"
```

It's highlighting the '{' curly brace on the constructor line under the LightningCounter class.

I'm not sure why I am getting this because I copy and pasted the script exactly as it was written.

Here is my App.js code:

```
<html>

<head>

  <title> Lightning Counter</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.9.0/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.9.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">


class LightningCounter extends React.Component {
 constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);

  this.state = {
  strikes: 0
};

this.timerTick = this.timerTick.bind(this);
}

timerTick() {
  this.setState({
   strikes: this.state.strikes + 100
});
}

componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
}

render() {
  var counterStyle = {
  color: "#66FFFF",
  fontSize: 50
};

var count = this.state.strikes.toLocaleString();

return (
  <h1 style={counterStyle}>{count}</h1>
);
}
}

class LightningCounterDisplay extends React.Component {
  render() {
   var commonStyle = {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
  };

var divStyle = {
  width: 250,
  textAlign: "center",
  backgroundColor: "#020202",
  padding: 40,
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  color: "#999999",
  borderRadius: 10
};

var textStyles = {
  emphasis: {
    fontSize: 38,
    ...commonStyle
  },
  smallEmphasis: {
    ...commonStyle
  },
  small: {
    fontSize: 17,
    opacity: 0.5,
    ...commonStyle
  }
};

return (
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <LightningCounter />
    <h2 style={textStyles.smallEmphasis}>LIGHTNING STRIKES</h2>
    <h2 style={textStyles.emphasis}>WORLDWIDE</h2>
    <p style={textStyles.small}>(since you loaded this example)</p>
  </div>
 );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<LightningCounterDisplay />,
document.querySelector("#container")
);



</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LightningCounterDisplay from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<LightningCounterDisplay />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @Anthony Chrome

Comment: Try different CDN links. Maybe I'm just having weird connectivity issues because I'm on a train, but https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js can't be found on my end. That said, your code does work when pasted into a codepen, albeit with the javascript separated out from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CDN links:

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core

It seems the current files cannot be found.